# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement

Tags: java, android, testng, appium

i'm Getting error “java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set io.appium.java_client.MobileElement field”

Error detail

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set
> io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement field
> test.pageObjectLogin.insertUserID to
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d27c0df4
>
> at
> sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
> at
> sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
> at
> sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
> at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)  at
> org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:117)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:105)
> at test.BasePage.(BasePage.java:25)   at
> test.pageObjectLogin.(pageObjectLogin.java:13)  at
> test.TestTODOLogin.testLogin(TestTODOLogin.java:12)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
> at
> org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
> at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)     at
> org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)     at
> org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)    at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:28)    at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:425)  at
> org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil.lambda$execute$0(ThreadUtil.java:68)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

using constructor like below

BasePage.java

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;

public class BasePage {

    public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    public BasePage(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver){
        this.driver = driver;;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)), this);
    }

    public void waitForVisibility(AndroidElement e){
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TestUtils.WAIT);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(e));
    }
    public String getAttribute(AndroidElement e, String attribute){
        waitForVisibility(e);
        return e.getAttribute(attribute);
    }
    public void sendKeys(AndroidElement e, String txt){
        waitForVisibility(e);
        e.sendKeys(txt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called page object model. first of all, using MobileElement and AndroidElement it's wrong step, MobileElement is most to recommended because works for android and ios. this source have clearer concept, visit https://blog.testproject.io/2018/07/31/page-object-model-appium-java-android/ check point number